# parsing json to a hash in java

Tags: java, json

I am new to java and am not able to think straight about this problem.

I have a text file which contains json objects as:

```
{"from":"1","to":["a","b"]}
```

and so on

I want to load these files in a hashmap so that "from" part is the key and "to" part is the value.
I am sure I am asking a very stupid question but any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?
THanks

Comment: It is doable, but I'd question the data model here. Why not just `{ "1": [ "a", "b" ] } `? This is legal JSON and much easier to handle by existing frameworks -- directly into a `Map` for that matter.

Comment: I think you may actually have to write code to do that.  Bummer.

Comment: Don't worry about "efficiently". Worry about "working". Since you have *nothing!?!* then it's a much better goal .. my first approach would just deserialize to POJO (hey, I like the contracts!) and then manipulate as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes):

```
// (1) deserialize JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
HashMap map = mapper.readValue(
    "{\"from\":\"1\",\"to\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}", HashMap.class);

// (2) reorder stuff (use a new Map object if needed, or delete obsolete keys)
map.put(map.get("from"), map.get("to"));
```

Output would be:

```
{to=[a, b], 1=[a, b], from=1}
```

or

```
{1=[a, b]}
```

if you would create a new map object in (2). As for efficiency, the heavier parsing part is handled by Jackson, which

> ... aims to be the best possible combination of fast, correct, lightweight, and ergonomic for developers.

Comment: Uh, will this really map `from` and `to` as keys and values respectively?